# How to show tags in double quotes?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, tippyjs

In the [Tippy](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/), I want to show tags in tooltip's. For this,

I tried:

```
<i style="font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-info tippy" data-tippy-content="You do not need to add &lt;style&gt;....&lt;/style&gt; tags."></i>
```

OR

```
<i style="font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-info tippy" data-tippy-content="You do not need to add <style>...</style> tags."></i>
```

But both of them not show tooltip's content correctly. I want it like this (This image created in Photoshop):

[image]

**EDIT**: But both of them show like this:

[image]

Comment: which result are you having?

Comment: according to [this](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/html-content/) , `you'll need to set  interactive: true`. Did you have it specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [`allowHTML: false`](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/all-options/) option to your `.tippy` class to make your HTML render as text rather than actually rendering the markup:

```js
tippy(".fa-info.allowHTML")

tippy(".fa-info", {
  allowHTML: false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i style="font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-info tippy " data-tippy-content="You do not need to add &lt;style&gt;....&lt;/style&gt; tags."></i>
<br />
<br />
<i style="font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-info tippy allowHTML" data-tippy-content=" Click <b>Send</b> button for sending..."></i>
```

Comment: Ooov, I understand now. But that time, I do not use URLs, bold styles, underline styles. What would you recommend for this?

Comment: @JackDaniels sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: For example, the other tooltip like this: `<i style="font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-info tippy" data-tippy-content="Click <b>Send</b> button for sending..."></i>`. In this example, Tippy do not make `Send` bolder.

Comment: @JackDaniels you can add another class called `allowHTML`  to the info buttons which you want HTML to be shown. If the class `allowHTML` isn't on the info button then the HTML will be shown as text

Answer (score 1):

If you leave a space between the escaped characters, it seems to show your expected result.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4"></script>
<button data-tippy-content="You do not need to add &lt; style &gt;....&lt; /style &gt; tags.">Text</button>
<script>
  tippy('button')
</script>
```